# Mixing times for the exclusion process with rejection

Tags: pr.probability, markov-chains

Consider the following Markov chain on $k$-subsets of $\{1,\ldots, L\}$, equivalently, sequences $x\in \{0,1\}^L$ with $k$ 1's.
Let $p_1,\ldots, p_L\in (0,1)$ and $q_i=1-p_i$.
At each step, choose an adjacent pair of positions $(i,i+1)$ at random, and attempt to swap the values of $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$. The two nontrivial cases are:

1. $x_i=0$, $x_{i+1}=1$. Accept this swap with probability $\min\{1,\frac{p_{i+1}q_i}{p_iq_{i+1}}\}$; otherwise stay at the same state.
2. $x_i=1$, $x_{i+1}=0$. Accept this swap with probability $\min\{1,\frac{p_{i}q_{i+1}}{p_{i+1}q_{i}}\}$.

This is a Metropolis-Hastings acceptance ratio, so it is easy to check that the chain is ergodic with stationary distribution
$$\pi (x) \propto \prod_{i:x_i=0} p_i \prod_{i:x_i=1} q_i. 
$$

What is the spectral gap and mixing time of this chain? (An upper bound on the mixing time is sufficient.) Ideally, if the $p_i,q_i$ are bounded away from 0, the mixing time would be $\widetilde O(L^3)$. More generally I would expect dependence on some quantity like $\max_{i,j} \max\{ \frac{p_i}{p_j}, \frac{q_i}{q_j}\}$.
More generally, I would like to answer the question when there are more than 2 states: Let the state space be the subset of $\{0,1,\ldots, k-1\}^L$ with fixed counts $|\{i:x_i=j\}|=c_j$. Let $\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} p_{j,i}=1$ (probabilities summing to 1 for each $1\le i\le L$). Then accept a swap between $x_i=a$ and $x_{i+1}=b$ with probability $\min\{1,\frac{p_{a,i+1}p_{b,i}}{p_{a,i}p_{b,i+1}}\}$.

The mixing time in the case where $p_i=q_i=\frac12$ is well understood; this is a symmetric exclusion process with mixing time $O(L^2 \log \min\{k,L-k\})$. (See Theorem 2.4 in [Lacoin 2016](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1457960399) for more precise asymptotics. Note the consider a continuous-time Markov process where each pair of neighboring sites gets exchanged with rate one, hence there is a factor of $L$ difference.)

My motivation for this problem comes from analyzing the mixing time of a parallel tempering Markov chain on a multimodal distribution; here $L$ is the number of temperatures and $x_i$ represents the mode that the sample at the $i$th temperature is close to.